# Al ocultar el Floating action button no se recibe más onNestedScroll Java Android

Tags: java, android, androidx

Intento ocultar y mostrar el `FloatingActionButton` dependiendo del scroll del contenido de un `RecyclerView`

- hacia abajo: se oculte el FloatingActionButton
- hacia arriba: se vuelve a mostrar el FloatingActionButton

Tengo lo siguiente extraído de ese [github](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter/blob/master/flexible-adapter-app/src/main/java/eu/davidea/utils/ScrollAwareFABBehavior.java) y adaptado para que funcione en AndroidX

```
public class ScrollAwareFABBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {

    public ScrollAwareFABBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull FloatingActionButton child, @NonNull View directTargetChild, @NonNull View target, int axes, int type) {
        return axes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL
                || super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild, target, axes, type);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull final FloatingActionButton child, @NonNull View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed, int type, @NonNull int[] consumed) {
        super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, type, consumed);

        if (dyConsumed > 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            child.hide();
        } else if (dyConsumed < 0 && child.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            child.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    child.show();
                }
            }, 200L);
        }

    }

}
```

El problema que tengo es que al ocultar el `FloatingActionButton` luego el evento `onNestedScroll` deja de recibir datos, con lo cual no se puede volver a mostrar.

He realizado las pruebas de no usar `.hide()` a cambio he probado con `.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` y funciona, el botón circular se oculta de golpe sin animación y se vuelve a mostrar con animación.

¿Es posible simular la animación de `.hide()` pero luego deje la visibilidad del `FloatingActionButton` en `View.INVISIBLE`?

Answer (score 0):

Buscando por [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41153619/floating-action-button-not-visible-on-scrolling-after-updating-google-support/41386278#41386278) he encontrado esa solución

Se puede forzar la visibilidad final al usar el método `.hide()`

```
child.hide(new FloatingActionButton.OnVisibilityChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onHidden(FloatingActionButton fab) {
        super.onShown(fab);
        fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Implementación final **ScrollAwareFABBehavior.java**

```
public class ScrollAwareFABBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {

    public ScrollAwareFABBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull FloatingActionButton child, @NonNull View directTargetChild, @NonNull View target, int axes, int type) {
        return axes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL
                || super.onStartNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, directTargetChild, target, axes, type);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNestedScroll(@NonNull CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, @NonNull final FloatingActionButton child, @NonNull View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed, int type, @NonNull int[] consumed) {
        super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed, type, consumed);

        if (dyConsumed > 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            // User scrolled down and the FAB is currently visible -> hide the FAB
            child.hide(new FloatingActionButton.OnVisibilityChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onHidden(FloatingActionButton fab) {
                    super.onShown(fab);
                    fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
        } else if (dyConsumed < 0 && child.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            // User scrolled up and the FAB is currently not visible -> show the FAB
            child.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    child.show();
                }
            }, 200L);
        }

    }

}
```

Asignación del behavior al FloatingActionButton

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="com.example.webserveis.testkeyvalue.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />
```